# Why ScrollView not scrollable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a fragment layout with some texts and two images at the lower end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.MyFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/24dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="Description"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_my_start_front"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_my_start_header" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_front"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/myapp_perso_rotated"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fragment_my_start_back"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_my_start_description" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/myapp_perso_back_rotated"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fragment_my_start_front"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_my_start_description" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:text="1. Image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_my_start_front"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/fragment_my_start_front" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:text="2. Image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_my_start_back"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/fragment_my_start_back" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And on the bottom I have a next bottom. (On older low resolution devices) The images are cut off at the ScrollViews bottom. This is not an error. But I would like to scroll up so that I can see the rest of the images. The ScrollView only  moves for a millimeter and I cant see the whole `ImageView`.

**So how can I make the whole ScrollView scrollable?**

Comment: Try adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" to your Linear Layout

Comment: Try to add `marginBottom` to `20dp`. May be this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MyFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/next_button"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/24dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="Description"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_my_start_front"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_my_start_header" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_front"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/myapp_perso_rotated"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fragment_my_start_back"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_my_start_description" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/myapp_perso_back_rotated"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fragment_my_start_front"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_my_start_description" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:text="1. Image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_my_start_front"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/fragment_my_start_front" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:text="2. Image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_my_start_back"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/fragment_my_start_back" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does not solve my problem. Scaling a bit better, but on low resolution devices (a small area) still behind button...

Answer (score 0):

I think the bottom of the images were cut because we didn't try to attach the images to the bottom of its parent. I tried adding the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to both *images* of your layout. After all of this I removed some unnecessary codes such as `mergin` and `fillViewport`, I got this code below. I don't have images you use so i use images from [this address](https://www.google.com.mm/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi47oWH8ZnfAhVai3AKHZFBCCsQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tradesy.com%2Fi%2Fmaison-margiela-black-designer-sample-long-workoffice-dress-size-12-l%2F19670630%2F&psig=AOvVaw2T5L_TD1zVAB3MAPjaP73Y&ust=1544690051308005) (P.S. I am sorry I didn't test in physical or virtual devices as I got slow pc and devices which is low in resolution.)

Here is my final code (Hope this helps) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_myStartHeader_fragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_myStartDes_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_myStartHeader_fragment" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/_1_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_myStartDes_fragment" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/_2_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_myStartDes_fragment" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_front"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/sample"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_my_start_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:src="@drawable/sample"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fragment_my_start_front"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```